# clustering over sphere surface

Tags: clustering

I have two algorithms, both of which create points on the surface of a higher dimensional sphere (say in $\mathbb{R}^n$). Now, I want to check, which algorithm gives a more uniform spread of points over the surface of the sphere. In lower dimensional cases like $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ both perform well but I want to check in higher dimension, say $n \geq 50$. I believe, some kind of clustering algorithm may help but I don't know which one to use in this situation (since the points are on surface and not inside). Is there a way to solve this problem ?

I can generate as many points as required for both the algorithms, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't have many specifics, so my assumption is that you need a way to check how uniform a distribution of points over a sphere is, so as to compare your two algos.

Here are two simple suggestions:

- Empirically estimate the entropy or uniformity. Essentially, divide the sphere into segments (e.g. in spherical coordinates, but [be careful](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html)) and count the number of points that fall into each segment. You could then measure the entropy of the histogram (i.e. if $n_i$ points fall into area $i$, and $N$ points were sampled in total, then $p_i = n_i/N$ and the entropy is $\mathbb{H}=-\sum_ip_i\log p_i$. Higher entropy means more uniformity. You could also compute the variance in the set of observed probability values to estimate uniformity, i.e. $\mu_p = \frac{1}{N}\sum_ip_i$, then $V = \frac{1}{N-1}\sum_j (p_j - \mu_p)^2$.
- Fit a [von Mises distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution) to the data, and simply check the concentration parameter $\kappa$. As $\kappa\rightarrow 0$, the distribution approaches the uniform one. (See the link for how to do parameter estimation).